# Unable to highlight the next editable cell in Jtable on tabbing to next Row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Below is my custom logic to tab to the next editable cell. Adds row automatically when tabbed from a particular column.

**What works fine:**

When new row is added focus is automatically on the first row of next column so that when i start typing it types from first column of next row.

**What i need :**

Highlight the cell in focus so that the user knows that the focus is on first column of next row. At the moment although it types correctly into the cell we dont know visibly that it is pointing to that cell.

**Note :**

I have done this `table.cellSelectionEnabled(true);` and still doesnt work.

```
InputMap im = itemTable.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
final Action oldTabAction = itemTable.getActionMap().get(im.get(tab));
Action tabAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        oldTabAction.actionPerformed( e );
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
        int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
        FLItemRuleInfo itemRuleInfo = itemTableModel.getItemRuleInfoList().get(row);

        while (! itemTableModel.isCellEditable(row, column) )
        {

            if((itemRuleInfo.getItem()==null || itemRuleInfo.getItem().getItemId()==null || itemRuleInfo.getItem().getItemId().isEmpty())){
                column=1;
                break;
            }
            column += 1;
            if (column == columnCount)
            {
                column = 1;
                row +=1;
            }
           /* if (row == rowCount)
            {
                row = 0;
            }*/
            if (row == table.getSelectedRow()
            &&  column == table.getSelectedColumn())
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        table.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);
        if(column==8 && (row == rowCount-1) && itemRuleInfo.getItem()!=null){
            itemTableModel.addRow(new FLItemRuleInfo());

        }                       

    }
};
itemTable.getActionMap().put(im.get(tab), tabAction);
```

Comment: Post your [mcve] demonstrating the problem. That is create a simple example using the DefaultTableModel and JTable with your custom Action so we can see the described behaviour. The only comment I have is that maybe the changeSelection() should be the last statement in the code.

Comment: This problem got resolved when i corrected my getValueAt method. Thanks

Comment: `This problem got resolved when i corrected my getValueAt method` - the code you posted doesn't even include a "getValueAt(...)" method. Once again this shows that you need to always create a post a [mcve] when you ask a question because until a problem is solved you don't know where the problem is, so posting random code doesn't help us.

Comment: Sure thanks will try to do it going forward . It was not done on purpose and I didnt even know where error was originating from.

Comment: `Sure thanks will try to do it going forward` - and yet you didn't include the [mcve] on your latest question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238405/jtable-cell-editing-doesnt-change-when-cell-is-validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getValueAt was returning null for a particular case and i changed null to an empty String "". This resolved the issue.